# vue component in laravel doesnt work only on server

Tags: mysql, laravel, vue.js, axios

I use a Vue component that gets data from the database (with Axios) and although it works well on the local machine, doesn't work on the server. also, all components which don't need to database, work correctly.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
```

Even I test my route path to load some data for the blade from the database and also they don't work,

I exported the database in `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` and imported it in MySQL on server
then update .env file on a server based on MySQL info on the server
and eventually

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:cache
```

I just tested the imported database, `mysql> USE imported_db; SHOW TABLES;` and I can see all tables
and my .env file is updated as well

Comment: "_Request failed with status code 404_" means the url/route was not found. Check if your route is there using `php artisan route:list`.

Comment: thank you @kerbh0lz yes it is, axios uses an api `axios.get('/api/list')` and this component works on local system, also it listed in `php artisan route:list` in server as well as other routes, but neither this component and other route path dont work on server, everything is same as local but i cant have them in server